# Failed 2003r2 Domain Controller

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain-controller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What needs to be done after a Domain Controller crash?](https://serverfault.com/questions/122356/what-needs-to-be-done-after-a-domain-controller-crash)

We have (had) two domain controllers, one of which recently failed. For a number of reasons, restoration is not on the list of things they are able to try. The box is old and replacement hardware is hard to come by. I did some research and found posts talking about performing a metadata cleanup. This seems straightforward enough but I have also read other places about seizing operations master roles. Even further I have read suggestions that you simply right click and delete the missing DC from AD users and computers.

The last idea does not seem like the right way to go.

I would think that I need to seize the OM roles from the missing server and then do a metadata cleanup. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's basically what you want to do.  Seize the OM role from the failed DC, clean up the metadata and DNS crud left behind, and move forward with a new DC.

Even with the metadata cleanup, however, you'll still need to manually remove the server object from Sites and Services as well as the computer object from Users and Computers. FSMO roles should also be transferred.

Also, keep an eye on applications that are looking to the failed DC for the Global Catalog.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should seize any of the 5 FSMO roles that are not on your remaining DC, not just the OM, then delete it from AD. Install a new server and make it a new DC.