# Restoring windows DC's

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-controller

Found this thread. [What needs to be done after a Domain Controller crash?](https://serverfault.com/questions/122356/what-needs-to-be-done-after-a-domain-controller-crash)

I have a related question and it is related to this statement from the thread. "it is critical that the old server is never brought back online". How about reusing the old server names. I have lost 4 servers due to a lightning strike and need to get them back up as quick as possible. New hardware etc. The old machines will never boot again. But I want to reuse the same server names so that all the scripting for backups / data exports / shortcuts for server hosted applications due not have to be redone. Is this going to be a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, re-using server names is fine.

For domain controllers, you'll want to seize any FSMO roles they hold, then delete the old computer accounts and metadata before joining the replacement systems to the domain.  (In 2008 and newer, you'll be prompted to do the metadata cleanup when deleting the computer account; see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816907%28v=ws.10%29.aspx))

Comment: To add, AD actually identifies the DC's via GUIDs (for instance the ones in _msdcs.**domain**) so re-using names is not a problem as long as you are doing it intentionally.

Comment: The existing answers are correct, as long as you remember to **FULLY CLEAN** your Active Directory _prior_ to joining the new server with the re-used name.  There are ton's of tutorials and pages listing how to fully delete a failed DC from a domain, but I'll recommend [http://www.petri.co.il/delete_failed_dcs_from_ad.htm](http://www.petri.co.il/delete_failed_dcs_from_ad.htm) as a great one to follow when stuck doing this.  Just remember, always clean everything before starting fresh.