# DC3 doesn't replicate with newly added DC1

Tags: active-directory, domain, azure, domain-controller

[image]

[DC 1 - LOTUS] [DC 2 - IRIS] [DC 3 - FLORA]

The picture above shows my domain network connection. My original DC1 was PYRUS, due to [some reasons](https://serverfault.com/questions/783652/issues-adding-new-dc-to-network-after-main-dc-broke-down), it is dead and be replaced by LOTUS.

I [Seize all FSMO roles](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/255504) on IRIS, did [metadata cleaup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728068(WS.10).aspx), rebuilt a new server, LOTUS, promoted it as DC and replicated everything from IRIS, then, transferred the FSMO roles to LOTUS. The detailed discussion can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/783652/issues-adding-new-dc-to-network-after-main-dc-broke-down).

After that, I did a [metadata cleanup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728068(WS.10).aspx) on DC 3, FLORA. However, LOTUS and FLORA don't replicate from each other. LOTUS is not known by FLORA. What can I do to allow them to replicate to each other again ?

The picture below shows the result after running `repadmin /showrepl /v`

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you run this command (a more detailed version than yours) and post the results? `repadmin /showrepl * /v /csv | ConvertFrom-Csv | select * -ExcludeProperty showrepl_columns,'destination dsa site','source dsa site' | ft -AutoSize`

Comment: @curropar I received the error `LDAP error 81 (Server Down) Wind32 Err 58.`

Comment: Ok, remove everything after `/csv` (it's just to make it pretty and ready to read), and try again, let's see to which server you're not arriving to.

Comment: @curropar Here is the result after running `repadmin /showrepl * /v /csv` : http://i.imgur.com/69Bn89d.png . It shows FLORA cannot replicate the active directory from IRIS. According to my network infrastructure, it is true that IRIS and FLORA don't sync with each other. Both of them should only replicate to and from LOTUS. I added LOTUS later than FLORA which replicated from IRIS, I think I need to make FLORA "knows" LOTUS and recognize it as the new main DC. I am not sure I am giving the correct suggestion with my limited knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Given your information, I assume you don't have (and don't plan to) connectivity between Branch A and Branch B.

Also, please be aware that there's nothing such as a "main DC": that was a Windows NT 3.5 thing, but it was gone with Windows 2000 Server. It was replaced with [FSMO roles](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/197132), and all those roles need to be accessible by all the DCs.

The next point is the replication itself. That is set up in "Windows Active Directory Sites and Services": you should there replicate your network infrastructure. This is a long but very good read about it: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755994(v=ws.10).aspx

You should basically set up there NTDS in Iris to Lotus, NTDS in Flora to Lotus, and remove any NTDS reference from Iris/Flora to Flora/Iris. And set NTDS in Lotus accordingly.

Further, I would recommend you to have two DCs on your central location, and have the FSMO roles distributed within them. This is not compulsive, but it will ease your life in case you've problems in the future.

Please let me know if you need further assistance.